# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when trying to update a Product with ShipStation's API

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, e-commerce

I'm having trouble updating a product in Shipstation.

I'm been using these 2 links to see how I should format the response:

https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/products/update/
https://www.any-api.com/shipstation_com/shipstation_com/docs/Products/_products_productId_/PUT

I believe I'm following it correctly, but I always get a 500 error message saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I've been using the GET request to get the product's attributes.
Then I update the attributes that need to be changed, and store it in `data` (which is an array of objects). Then I use the PUT request to send the data.

This is the relevant code:

```
function updateProducts(authString, data) {

  var baseProductUrl = `https://ssapi.shipstation.com/products/`;

  for(var d = 0; d < data.products.length; d++) { //for each product I'd like to update...

    var raw = data.products[d];
    raw = JSON.stringify(raw);

    var requestOptions = { 

      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Basic ${authString}`,
        "Content-Type": `application/json`,       
      },

      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    var productUrl = `${baseProductUrl}${data.products[d].productId}`;
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(productUrl, requestOptions);
  }
}
```

This is what `raw` (the data I'm sending to ShipStation) looks like:
The null values are simply what I receive from the GET request. I'd prefer those attributes stay empty.

```
{"aliases":null,
"productId":123456789, //placeholder
"sku":"sku", //placeholder
"name":"UV Bulb - 1GPM - 10\"",
"price":19.99,
"defaultCost":null,
"length":2,
"width":2,
"height":13,
"weightOz":7,
"internalNotes":null,
"fulfillmentSku":null,
"active":true,
"productCategory":null,
"productType":null,
"warehouseLocation":null,
"defaultCarrierCode":null,
"defaultServiceCode":null,
"defaultPackageCode":null,
"defaultIntlCarrierCode":null,
"defaultIntlServiceCode":null,
"defaultIntlPackageCode":null,
"defaultConfirmation":null,
"defaultIntlConfirmation":null,
"customsDescription":"UV Bulb - 1GPM - 10\"", //attribute I'd like to update
"customsValue":9.99, //attribute I'd like to update
"customsTariffNo":null,
"customsCountryCode":"US",
"noCustoms":null,
"tags":null}
```

So does anyone have any hints, or has anyone used ShipStation's API before and done a PUT request?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var requestOptions = { 

  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Basic ${authString}`,
    "Content-Type": `application/json`,       
  },

  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```

#### To:

```
var requestOptions = { 
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Basic ${authString}`,
  },
  payload: raw,
  contentType: "application/json",
};
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Can't believe it was such a simple fix. Thank you so much! btw payload in your answer is misspelled

Comment: @oscark Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the misspell, thank you for checking it. I would like to modify it. Thank you, too.